# Plone: Add permission to role

Tags: permissions, plone

In a Plone site there is a permission called "access inactive portal content". By default, this is granted to the roles "Manager" and "Owner".

I want to grant this permission to the role "Editor" as well, and I know I can just use the corresponding checkbox in the "Security" tab in the ZMI, but I'd like to do it programmatically in some sort of setup script. How would I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you have to create a new product and add a genericsetup step called "rolemap.xml" with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rolemap>
  <permissions>
    <permission name="Access inactive portal content" acquire="False">
      <role name="Editor" />
    </permission>
  </permissions>
</rolemap>
```

More info:

- http://plone.org/documentation/kb/genericsetup
- http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/generic-setup/reference/roles-and-permissions

Bye, Giacomo

Comment: Nice, thanks! But could it be that the rolemap isn't reevaluated on restart? I just added your code into an existing rolemap, and the permission didn't seem to change after restarting the plone instance.

Comment: Got it ... I have to reimport the permission map using the setup tool.

Comment: Exactly...genericsetup is automatically evaluated only during add-on's installation. You can force the evaluation by re-installing the add-on or manually, as you said, using portal_setup tool. Please remember to flag the question as answered.

Comment: Yeah, everything in GenericSetup is not about code changes or changes in memory, but is instead about persistent changes in the database.